# Repeating command for running external script?

Tags: shell, count, command

I have a script called `lorem.sh` which takes in the number of paragraphs(first argument) and number of lines in each paragraph(second argument) and prints random text of that format to standard out. I turned this into a vim key binding so I could enter this text into my file with :

```
nmap <leader>l :read ! ~/lorem.sh 1 100<CR>
```

This works but I was wondering if it would be possible to add a count to this command in the same way you can specify a count to other commands like `Ndd` to delete N lines below the current one. If I could have something like `N<leader>l` working, I could enter N paragraphs of text at once.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on `:help v:count`:

```
                    *v:count* *count-variable*
v:count     The count given for the last Normal mode command.  Can be used
        to get the count before a mapping.  Read-only.  Example: >
    :map _x :<C-U>echo "the count is " . v:count<CR>
<       Note: The <C-U> is required to remove the line range that you
        get when typing ':' after a count.
        When there are two counts, as in "3d2w", they are multiplied,
        just like what happens in the command, "d6w" for the example.
        Also used for evaluating the 'formatexpr' option.
        "count" also works, for backwards compatibility, unless
        |scriptversion| is 3 or higher.

                    *v:count1* *count1-variable*
v:count1    Just like "v:count", but defaults to one when no count is
        used.
```

You want

```
nnoremap <leader>l :execute 'read !~/lorem.sh' v:count1 '100'<CR>
```

(Notice I am using `nnoremap`; this is a good habit.)

Comment: your specific response did not work but i did some more digging in the part of the help file that you linked and I found **exactly** what I was looking for : the concatenation `.` operator and the `exe` command. This one worked for me in the end : `noremap <leader>l  :exe "read ! ~/lorem.sh " . "v:count1" . " 100<CR>"`

Comment: @FirstUser doh! I even wrote a QA about exec and variables